# Why the does AWS CLI use different AWS services on darwin (mac) vs. linux? When does the rds describe-db-instances command use STS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, botocore, aws-sts

Running

```bash
aws --profile=REDACTED --region=REDACTED rds describe-db-instances
```

fails for me on linux but succeeds on darwin (mac).

It seems that on my linux, a call is made to AWS's Simple Token Service that I don't have permissions to. But for some reason, that call is skipped on my mac.

Why might the first call run by the AWS CLI vary by system? Why would a call to the Simple Token Service be required when using the AWS CLI?

Is there perhaps something related to authentication or session management that I don't have configured properly on the linux machine I'm running on?

---

I confirmed I'm using the same version, `aws-cli/1.25.76 Python/3.10.8 Linux/6.0.11 botocore/1.27.75`, on each machine.

At first, the error appeared permissions-related

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: REDACTED is not authorized to perform: sts.AssumeRole on resource: REDACTED
```

I confirmed I do not have `sts.AssumeRole`.

However, while investigating, I accidentally made a typo and noticed something strange: on darwin, the first call made by the above command appears to be to the `rds` service, while on linux the first call is to the `sts` service.

For example,

```bash
aws --profile=REDACTED --region=typo-region rds describe-db-instances
```

yields this on my darwin machine

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://rds.typo-region.amazonaws.com/"
```

and this on my linux machine

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://sts.typo-region.amazonaws.com/"
```

I'm not yet familiar enough with how the `aws` command and it's `boto` internals work to understand why the extra call to `sts` is being made on one machine and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the profiles are differently configured on the two machines, one is using a "regular" role / profile with ordinary credentials simply set while the other is using a profile with a [`role_arn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) set prompting the CLI to perform an `AssumeRole` call into that target role.

Alternatively it *may* be the case that one machine has the nested credentials already retrieved and cached, while the other one does not. And if you removed the permissions / changed the trust relationship in the meantime the old credentials are still valid while the new credentials cannot be retrieved.